REACT Page Buttons Become Unresponsive
I have a REACT website that sits in an IFrame within another website. It works perfectly, but now I hear sometimes the buttons, textboxes and all other form controls become un-clickable or unresponsive. As a developer, I had only seen this happen when developing (i.e., running from VS Code) and I use developer mode on the browser, and only in Firefox. Also, when I'm developing, the page is running on its own (not being hosed by a third party), so it even happens when not inside an IFrame.
However a client has now raised this problem on the live website. I asked if she had ever pressed F12, and she said she didn't. Her first experience was that she could only click on a button's right edge on the page. When I went to see for myself, nothing was clickable or responsive. Textboxes could not be entered into, etc. And this was on Chrome.
Only the website inside the IFrame is affected. The host website is still responsive. If the whole website is refreshed, the problem goes away. For my part, I have not been able to replicate the problem on the live site, except by using developer mode on the browser, and it happens on both Chrome and Firefox. But it does not always happen. I don't know if there are steps to make it happen. Furthermore, there is nothing on the console to tell me anything happened.

if it happened only in iframe, maybe it is a cross-origin-related issue, or maybe something causing the website in the iframe memory to leak and hang.
